# lombok compilation errors when running maven-surefire-plugin:test

Tags: java, maven, lombok

When running `mvn package`, I sometimes see compilation errors in the test phase. The error message provided is `Unresolved compilation problems`.

I believe this is because the test itself is trying to use a lombok generated class:

```
ResultTest.java
---------------
import my.package.Result.ResultBuilder; // first compilation error here

public void resultBuilderTest() {
    ResultBuilder resultBuilder = Result.builder();
}

Result.java
-----------
@Data
@Builder
public class Result {
    private int resultCount;
    private List<String> results;
}
```

The dependency in `pom.xml` is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I run `mvn clean package`, the tests work fine. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was caused by background compilation by my IDE (VSCode), which didn't understand the Lombok annotations. After adding a Lombok plugin and re-compiling, I can no longer reproduce the error.